# How to correctly translate an integer into a string in qt

Tags: qt

I have some problems with this code

```
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    if (time.hour() > edit_hour)
    edit_hour -= edit_hour - time.hour();
    if ( time.minute() > edit_minute)
    edit_minute -= edit_minute - time.minute();
    if (time.hour() < edit_hour)
    edit_hour += time.hour() - edit_hour;
    if (time.minute() > edit_minute)
    edit_minute += time.minute() - edit_minute;
    edit1_hour = to_string(edit_hour);
    edit1_minute = to_string(edit_minute);
    QString text = edit1_hour + ":" + edit1_minute;
```

After compilation (more precisely attempt) I have got a messege like:

> ‘to_string’ was not declared in this scope
>   edit1_hour=to_string(edit_hour);
>             ^~~~~~~~~

How to solve it?

Comment: add `#include <string>` and change to  `std::to_string(...)`. Provide a [MRE]

Comment: I already add it, also I include cstring lib

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Are you compiling to at least the [`c++11`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) standard.

Comment: Do you want `std::string`? Why not using `QString::number`?